# Working freelance 

Tags: freelance, networking, marketing

So i've been trying for nearly a year to gain any kind of internship, work experience, runner position, within the audio post area and have had no success. I'm thinking of trying to go freelance but don't really know where to start or how I would market myself to gain any paying clients. Just wondering if anyone else has been in this same position and how they started out?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Yes, many of us have. Unfortunately, you don't really decide to go freelance. It happens when you build up a client list (most of the time).

Welcome to the great catch 22 of audio production.  :-)

Answer (score 2):

You can start by getting a network identity. Stuff like a cool name/brand, logo, professional website can only help.

Once that's done you can start researching your market and emailing possible clients. It's a lot of work and for a few months (or years?) won't pay off, but if you keep at it it will eventually start working for you.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

The internship allowed me to later be a freelancer. In Germany, internships are paid and  you're never making coffee unless you want one. My internship was very hands-on. Oh, and I bugged the hell out of the guy to give me the internship after I was an intern in a different area at the same company. Maybe you could be more creative regarding your application into these internships. For example, take something they did, and try to make it better, then send it to the right person and ask for a cup of coffee to talk about it.

Answer (score 0):

Networking is one of the most important things that I've learned by doing freelance work for the past two years. Word gets around and if you're good at a particular thing, find a way to market yourself around that skill set. Another big thing is to always act professionally, no matter what the job entails. Once people get to see that you're serious and you mean business, your name will come up more often than others and you'll find yourself having no problem finding work.

Answer (score 0):

What about Sky? You're in England, right?

Comment: Hey, yeah i'm in England